# How to get/post/update/delete data from a mongoDB database with an iOS app?

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb

I just finished creating an iOS app for a little startup and they have their own servers and database.

They have the backend architecture using apache, NodeJS, Express, MONGODB.

I created the app using firestore and firebase. The question is how can I link the app to that database server? They have all the info about users in that database.

They also have a webapp built using react. So what I need is to basically sync the app with the webapp .

Can somebody give me a little tutoring regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good approach but it might be helpful.
review the following example
https://github.com/ahmmug/CRUD-Operation-Node.js